# how to download m3u video in IOS app?

Tags: ios, video, download, m3u, m3u8

I'm developing an IOS application which will download some videos to local so that users can watch those videos offline. But currently, a lot of videos are m3u and m3u8 format. As I know m3u and m3u8 is just a video list. So my question is how I can download the real video file into local and play them for m3u and m3u8 format.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `m3u` or `m3u8` is a playlist, does not contain music data.

To parse the file, you can follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914330/parsing-of-m3u-files-in-objective-c-for-iphone-from-file-system-or-url). After you parsed the file, you can fetch the real media URL and load it with media player.

Reference of M3U file format in Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U

**UPDATE:** Furthermore, another guy is doing similar thing. You can review his code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833731/how-to-play-m3u-audio-stream-in-ios-app).

Comment: Thanks for your quick update, but it seems you didn't answer my question. I want to know how to download m3u8 format video and play it on local.

Comment: You can use `NSURLConnection` to download file. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204010/how-to-use-nsurlrequest-nsurlconnection-to-download-an-mp3-file-to-app

Comment: Yes, I know how to download a file. But as you said, the m3u8 file is a playlist and the real media segment url is in it. How can I download  the whole media file?

Comment: Download the m3u8 > Parse the file > get the media URL > Download the media using the media URL

Comment: Shivan, thanks for your patience. Since it is very important for me, I'd like to clarify this with you. The following is a part of the m3u file.I can figure out the media url. After all media segments (.mp4.ts) are downloaded, how can I play them? Do I need to generate a my new m3u file to play them ? #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:25
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:12,
http://112.25.32.132/6777C380A074A78CDF04A6E64/03000811004C232BC7B8B20365E2F73663CAD1-2A48-99D6-F595-375BC7396F7F.mp4.ts?ts_start=0&ts_end=11&ts_seg_no=0&ts_keyframe=1
#EXTINF:17.48,

Comment: use `UIWebView` to load the m3u playlist is easier in your case, if your playlist contains mp4 segments. see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986313/http-live-streaming-for-iphone-and-why-we-use-m3u8-file

Comment: @Raptor : How can I save the streaming video into gallery ?

Comment: @VineeshTP Please ask in a new question, as this is not related to this old question.

Comment: @Raptor : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068666/the-operation-couldn-t-be-completed-cocoa-error-1-phphotolibrary

Comment: @Raptor : if any updates,  please answer. for above question,