# The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.) - PHPhotoLibrary

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, url, photolibrary

Hi I am trying to save a downloaded mp4 file to my gallery.

Downloading the url by using , `downloadTask`

in

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){
}
```

I am getting the url

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8D761DFE-C050-426D-B91C-61DE441FB496/Library/Caches/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/Downloads/com.te.dn/CFNetworkDownload_KFSYSW.tmp
```

I am creating a path by using,

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/file1.mp4"))

if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: destinationURLForFile.path){

        }
        else{
            do {
                try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
                // show file

            }catch{
                print("An error occurred while moving file to destination url")
            }
        }
```

I could successfully move the file (not getting any error while moving).

Then I trying to save the file getting error

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: destinationURLForFile.path)
```

url value is :

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8DF0C849-56A1-42B3-A081-0C992D18F973/Documents/file1.mp4


        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: url)
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your video was successfully saved", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "f")
            }

        }
```

o/p : Error :- `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error -1.)`

Comment: You should look into this answer that will solve your problem. [Save video in photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479903/swift-download-a-video-from-distant-url-and-save-it-in-an-photo-album)

Comment: Have you figured this problem @Vineesh TP? This is driving me crazy since couple hours.

Comment: @manonthemoon : please check the data is avilable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can not save video from m3u8 file.

But, we can offline-download the video, Also can't move to video to gallery.

Here the apple code [HLSCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HLSCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)